# Java System.getProperty returns wrong string in case value has special characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass user id and password from command line as below

```
mvn clean verify -Dtest.email="myemail@yahoo.com" -Dtest.password="pass$word$"
```

Accessing these within program

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("test.email"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("test.password"));
```

returns

```
myemail@yahoo.com
pass
```

Can someone clarify why string with $ sign is getting truncated and work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should quote the dollar sign like below:

```
mvn clean verify -Dtest.email="myemail@yahoo.com" -Dtest.password="pass\$word\$"
```

Otherwise you'll get empty string since no value is assigned to the "word" variable.

Comment: can you please clarify why getProperty doesn't return everything between double quotes ? I read the method documentation but didn't find about special characters and escaping needs.   Also just to clarify  "word" is not variable but the password value itself contains special characters $

Comment: @vikramvi From the behavior of your program, I assumed you're running UNIX system. The `$` sign is a variable symbol, and since you didn't set any variable called `word`, it'll get the default value of an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  I'm using Mac command line to pass 2 arguments to java program , as I can't hard code user id & pwd.